# How to disable one specific tableView cell in ios Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have created a custom UITableViewCell.I have only two rows in my tableView. Now I want to disable 2nd cell when 1st is tapped and disable 1st cell when 2nd is tapped.
How can I do that ? please Help and guide

Comment: Did you check the `selection` of `UITableViewCell` ?

Comment: you can maintain array of bools and update value when you need to enable and disable

Comment: send me your mail id. I will send you demo.

Comment: I also have the same issue. can i Update this Question with my code?

Comment: @VishalSonawane umairafzal10@yahoo.com

Answer (score 2):

Implement the `UITableViewDelegate` method `willSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

In that method, return the `indexPath` value that's passed to you if you want the user to be able to select it, or return nil if you don't want it to be selectable.

I'll leave it to you to figure out the logic that decides when different cells should/should not be selectable.

Comment: Why not checking it by using 'shouldHighlight' method? logically, I assume it is better than returning a nil indexpath, please advice. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
  tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: (indexPath.row + 1) % 2, inSection: 0))?.userInteractionEnabled = false
}
```

Comment: No, that's a UITableViewDelegate method, and it won't let you control which items are selectable or not.